# Invalid escape in lua nvim_create_user_command in Neovim for Find/Replace command

Tags: replace, lua, neovim

I would like to define a permanent function in Neovim called Gloss which will run through a document and perform the following Find and Replace:

```
%s/^G:.\(.*\)/\\gloss{\1}/g | %s/^E:.\(.*\)/{\1}/g
```

I have it set up as the following in a .lua file in my ~/.config/nvim folder:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Gloss', function()
    '%s/^G:.\(.*\)/\\gloss{\1}/g | %s/^E:.\(.*\)/{\1}/g'
end, {})
```

However, whenever I try and source this .lua file, it says that there is an invalid escape sequence near ''%s/^G:.'. For the life of me I cannot figure out how this isn't working I have tried "fixing" the escape sequences but nothing is working. For reference, when I run the function in Neovim as:

```
call nvim_create_user_command('Gloss', '%s/^G:.\(.*\)/\\gloss{\1}/g | %s/^E:.\(.*\)/{\1}/g',    {'bang': v:true})
```

I can then call :Gloss perfectly fine and it does precisely what I want it to do so it is clearly something with the way I'm defining the function *within* the .lua file in my dot files. Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure the solution is silly but I have scoured the internet for hours and cannot find anybody trying to define a static recallable Find and Replace in vim for repeated use. Thank you so much!!

I have tried "fixing" the invalid escape but nothing is helping with that. Also obviously looking on the internet. For reference, changing the way the Find and Replace is written changes nothing it always says invalid escape.

Comment: Did you try re-escaping each backslash?